# How to save values outside of a Laravel each loop

Tags: php, laravel

I am not fully understanding Laravel Collections.
I need to know how save external values while iterating through a Lavavel Collection using the each(function(n){})

For example:

```
static public myFunction($laravelCollection) ={
   $arr=[];
    $laravelCollection->each(function($a){
    $arr[]=$a
   });
   return $arr
}

...
$exampleArr = SomeClass::myFunction($aCollection);
var_dump($exampleArr);
//desired results:  the var_dump of the collection
```

It seams that $arr inside of the each function is local to the function. How can I accomplish the above?  I realize that if it was NOT a static function,  I could simply use a $this->arr instead, but I need to do the above using a static function.

Comment: If that's all you're doing - why can you not simply use `return $laravelCollection->toArray()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying a variable inside a laravel collection, you will have to use `use()` method with reference `&`.

```
$arr = [];
$laravelCollection->each(function($a) use(&$arr) {
    $arr[] = $a;
});
```

Or even better, since you are simply converting your collection into an array:

```
$arr = $laravelCollection->toArray();
```

Check out the [collection docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#introduction).

Comment: is it possible to pass in multiple values? Example:  use(&$arr, &$anotherArr) - how can I do this?

Comment: ANSWER: To use multiple vars, use(&$arr1,&$arr2) etc